# Creating nxm index list of array a

Tags: python, array, numpy

Here is the problem:

> Given a numpy array 'a' that contains n elements, denote by b the set
> of its unique values ​​in ascending order, denote by m the size of
> array b. You need to create a numpy array with dimensions  n×m , in
> each row of which there must be a value of 1 in case it is equal to
> the value of the given index of array b, in other places it must be 0.

```
import numpy as np


def convert(a):
    b = np.unique(sorted(a))
    result = []
    for i in a:
        result.append((b == i) * 1)
    return np.array(result)


a = np.array([1, 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1])
b = np.unique(sorted(a))
print(convert(a))
```

This is my solution. is there some improvments that I can make?
I'm not sure about declaring regular list to the result and then converting it into np.array.

Comment: Please do not edit the question with suggestions from answers. If you want a new round of feedback with updated code, you can post a new question.

Comment: I've mistaken, when copied the code from my editor, that line was unnecessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove `sorted`**

From the docs: [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) returns the sorted unique elements of an array.

You can simply remove the call to `sorted`:

```
b = np.unique(sorted(a))

# produces the same result as

b = np.unique(a)
```

---

**List comprehension**

In most cases you can and should avoid this pattern of list creation:

```
result = []
for i in a:
    result.append((b == i) * 1)
```

It can be replaced by a concise list comprehension and directly passed to `np.array`:

```
result = np.array([(b == i) * 1 for i in a])

# or directly return it (if applicable)
return np.array([(b == i) * 1 for i in a])
```

List comprehensions are more pythonic and often faster. Generally, not mutating the `list` object is also less error-prone.

---

There might be a better way to map `lambda x: (uniques == x) * 1` over the input array `a`. Here's a discussion on the topic on StackOverflow: [Most efficient way to map function over numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35215161/most-efficient-way-to-map-function-over-numpy-array). Seems like using `np.vectorize` should be avoided for performance reasons.

Using `map` might be similiar to the list comprehension performance-wise (I did **not** properly test performance here):

```
def convert_listcomp(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a)
    return np.array([(b == i) * 1 for i in a])

def convert_map(a):
    uniques = np.unique(a)
    return np.array(list(map(lambda x: (uniques == x) * 1, a)))
```

Answer (score 1):

There's always the one-liner that assumes `a` is a row vector (1d array):

```py
(a.reshape((-1, 1)) == np.unique(a)).astype(int)
```

This works by broadcasting the `==` operation. Let us see how.

When you ask `numpy` to apply an operation, first it checks if the dimensions are compatible. If they aren't, an exception is raised. For example, try typing `np.ones(3) - np.ones(4)` in an interpreter. After pressing enter, you should see the message

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,) (4,).
```

This happens, because `3 != 4`. Duh. But there's more.

Try `a.reshape((-1, 1)) == np.unique(a)`. Despite `n!=m` usually holding, `numpy` happily calculates a matrix of shape `(n, m)`. Why?

This is the magic of [broadcasting](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

> When operating on two arrays, NumPy compares their shapes element-wise. It starts with the trailing (i.e. rightmost) dimensions and works its way left. Two dimensions are compatible when
>
> 1. they are equal, or
> 2. one of them is 1
>
> If these conditions are not met, a ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together exception is thrown, indicating that the arrays have incompatible shapes. The size of the resulting array is the size that is not 1 along each axis of the inputs.

How is this rule applied here? Well, the shape of `x = a.reshape((-1, 1))` is `(n, 1)`, the shape of `y = np.unique(a)` is `(1, m)`, so the second point from above holds. Therefore numpy expands `x` from shape `(n, 1)` to `xx` of shape `(n, m)` by "copying" (to the best of my knowledge there's no copying occurring) its values along the second axis, i.e. respecting the rule

```
xx[j, k] = x[j] for all j=1..n, k=1..m.
```

Similarly, `y` is expanded from shape `(1, m)` to `yy` of shape `(n, m)` respecting

```
yy[j, k] = y[k] for all j=1..n, k=1..m
```

and the operation is applied to `xx` and `yy` as usual, i.e.

```
x == y   ~>   xx == yy   ~>    :)
```