# Finding distance between vectors of matrices

Tags: python, array, numpy, matrix, mathematics

So here is the problem:

> Given 2D numpy arrays 'a' and 'b' of sizes  n×m  and  k×m
> respectively and one natural number 'p'. You need to find the
> distance(Euclidean) of the rows of the matrices 'a' and 'b'. Fill the
> results in the  k×n  matrix. Calculate the distance with the following
> formula
> $$
> D(x, y) = \left( \sum _{i=1} ^{m}
> \left| x_i - y_i \right|^p
> \right) ^{1/p}
> ; x,y \in R^m
> $$
> (try to prove that this is a distance). Extra points for writing
> without a loop.

And here is my solution:

```
import numpy as np


def dist_mat(a, b, p):
    result = []
    print(result)
    for vector in b:
        matrix = a - vector
        print(matrix)
        result.append(list(((matrix ** p).sum(axis=1))**(1/p)))
    return np.array(result)


a = np.array([[1, 1],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 3],
              [4, 5]])
b = np.array([[1, 1],
              [-1, 0]])
p = 2
print(dist_mat(a, b, p))
```

I'm not sure about using Python `list` and then converting it into `np.array`, is there a better way?

Comment: Does this code pass all the testcases? It seems to me that you would want `matrix = abs(a - vector)` according to the provided formula. Doesn't matter for an even value `p`, but does for odd values. Might be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah, that part was incorrect, thank you for the correction.

Comment: I know you want your own solution from scratch, but you might have a look at `scipy.spatial.distance_matrix()` for testing. https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance_matrix.html

Answer (score 1):

This is an old enough question that shooting for the extra points is hopefully not going to step on anyone's toes. So let me be the broadcast guy, i.e. this is a loop-free version.

It is perhaps better to first read either the numpy documentation on broadcasting, or a related [answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/259207/creating-nxm-index-list-of-array-a/259261#259261).

### We start with solving the one-column case.

In this case the matrices are of size `n x 1` and `k x 1`. We need to turn these into a matrix of size `k x n`.

Well, to get there by broadcasting, we need to take the transpose of one of the vectors. The problem calls for the first one to be transposed. Thus we have the matrix `a.T` of size `1 x n` and `b` of size `k x 1`.

Then the solution is just

```py
    # shape is (k, n)
    (np.abs(a.T - b) ** p) ** (1/p).
```

### The case with multiple columns

The matrices are of size `n x m` and `k x m`. To be able to reuse the previous idea, we have to turn these into arrays of shape `1 x n x m` and `k x 1 x m`. This can be done using `np.expand_dims`:

```py
    # shape is (k, n, m)
    np.expand_dims(a, 0) - np.expand_dims(b, 1)
```

Looks good. All that remains is to take the absolute value, then the `p`th power, then sum up along the last dimension, lastly take `p`th root.

```py
    # shape is (k, n)
    (np.abs(np.expand_dims(a, 0) - np.expand_dims(b, 1))**p).sum(axis=-1)**(1/p)
```

Comment: All insights are welcome here on CR - there's no need to worry about "stepping on toes"!  This is certainly a good way to simplify the code, and shows the reasoning as to how it works and why it's better - exactly what we want from a good answer.  Keep them coming!

Comment: @TobySpeight right, thank you. I never seem to know when is a complete rewrite appropriate as a review. Especially when the question smells like homework.

Answer (score 0):

`np.array()` takes any kind of nested sequence. So, it isn't necessary to convert to a list before appending to `result`.

```
def dist_mat(a, b, p):
    result = []
    for vector in b:
        matrix = np.abs(a - vector)
        result.append(((matrix ** p).sum(axis=1))**(1/p))

    return np.array(result)
```